# comparing 50 pairs of input textboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I have 50 pairs of input textboxes, i.e.

```
<input type="text" id="name_0" /><input type="text" id="name_1" />
<input type="text" id="dept_0" /><input type="text" id="dept_1" />
```

...

```
<input type="text" id="age_0" /><input type="text" id="age_1" />
<input type="text" id="weight_0" /><input type="text" id="weight_1" />
```

i.e 50 variables of these.

When the page loads, I populate each pair with identical data.

What is the best way to check if the `_0` is different from the `_1`?

then returning a message showing which pair has changed.

The comparison should take place once the values have been changed and a button is clicked.

Comment: When do you want to compare the values? While typing or at some other event?

Comment: On a button click event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tomalak's answer should work, but just in case your `input`s are scattered or not necessarily beside each other, something like this should suffice.

```
$('input:text[id$="_0"]').each(function() {
    var new_id = this.id.replace('_0','_1');

    if ($(this).val() !== $('input#'+new_id).val()) {
        // not the same
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$("input[type=text]").each(function () {
  var $this = $(this);

  if ( /_0$/.test(this.id) ) {
    if ( $this.val() != $this.next("input").val() ) {
      $this.css("color", "red"); // or whatever
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var changed = [];
$("[id$=_0]").each(function() {
  var name = this.id.replace("_0", "");
  if (this.value != $("#" + name  + "_1").val()) {
      changed.push(name);
  }
});
console.log(changed);
```